# Populate an array of array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I must populate an array of array of objects to get something like this:

```js
let dataObj = [
    [
        { content: "test1"}, 
        { content: "test2"},
        { content: "test3"}
    ], 
    [
        { content: "test4"},
        { content: "test5"},
        { content: "test6"}
    ]
]
```

I start from an array of arrays like this:

```js
data = [["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test4", "test5", "test6"]]
```

---

I tried with:

```js
let dataObj = <any>[[{ }]];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    dataObj[i][j].content = data[i][j];
  }
}
```

but after populating the first ([0][0]) it stops and the error is an

> uncaught in promise...

(I work in Angular-TypeScript)

I tried also with:

```js
dataObj.push(i,j,{content: data[i][j]});
```

It gets a result but it's completely wrong.

Comment: The provided `dataObj` was incorrect, especially for the second array item. Kindly revise and update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an array into the root array.
2. Add an object into the nested array.

```js
let dataObj: { content: any;[key: string]: any }[][] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   dataObj.push([]);

   for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      dataObj[i].push({ content: data[i][j] })
   }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can work with `.map()`.

```js
let dataObj: { content: any;[key: string]: any }[][] = [];

dataObj = data.map(x => 
  x.map(y => {
    return { content: y };
  })
);
```

[Sample TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQNooERhAZzARnQBoJMcwAmIkrXAZnQF1iMawAWK03AVk9YDZGDANwBYAFATQkWPADyAIwBWALggBvCAGMA9gDssBtTD0BPYSgDWIU2twAnAJZ6A5g2NmIAXxQNfSVBEJCQB6EIgAZR1gAFcwR30IPAkAMx17CAAKaQhHAIAGYVyIAB5oOBgAOlBXMAALIscAaiaASg0JCC7ZGEUlSoAHGOw6zN9WsUlxLog0jOzwCCUCouWynpRHBmqQWoallvb1Tpnuir7N7aGRzM1dA12wNQ2tlCUGb1aT7wkvYPF7thoiBqjoXJl0FFYvFEngADp6Kg9PoTf5hSLROIJPQQcj-ZHKAI9SoAWxgA0yAA8kAA+b6U0nkzKmWkdaanCD2cAxew4zToe6GMDoNQsryTGZeL7iVFTQHA0HgyGYmE48gIpHnZQTIA)

Comment: GREAT! the first way (which I understand better : ) works perfectly, like a charm! Thanks Yong Shun!

Comment: @Nicola I would suggest you spend some time learning the second approach. Writing less code reduces leaves room for fewer bugs, reduces our cognitive load, and can communicate intentions more clearly.